# Objective-C how to present an action sheet from tab bar that overlaps the current view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, overlays

I'd like to add an action sheet that appears when tab bar center item is clicked. like in this example: 
[this is how it shows when center item is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K8y0.png)

i have added the tab bar from storyboard and its working fine.
the hard part of it is how to keep the previous view and overlay the action sheet.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: the tab bar is created from storyboard so there is no code. @mychemicalro

Comment: not sure if you can create a class file for UITabBarViewController for your storyboard tab bar If you can then my answer would work.

Comment: @rv7284 ok i'll try it. thank you

Comment: How about this https://github.com/wwdc14/HyPopMenuView ?

Comment: @jiama seems interesting i'll try it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this delegate function to intercept tab selection

for swift 3

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if self.tabBarController.customizableViewControllers.index(of: viewController) == 2 {
       //display action sheet
       return false
    }
    return true
}
```

for objective c

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
//same logic above
}
```

Comment: Sorry but can you tell me where i have to add this function? I tried this concept in appDelegate but it didn't work also in the view that i want to present the action sheet, it is not running that what i have noticed after debug. thank you for your time

Comment: you will have to create a new file subClass of UITabBarController, after that assign  delegate and it will work there.

Comment: first of all - question is about `Objective-C` so rewrite your answer in this language please. Maybe it causes the problem of understanding

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create an empty view controller, and present the action sheet in `viewDidAppear`. But you have to think of what to do (e.g. which view controller to display)

- after the user chose an option
- if the user cancels the action

Comment: the hard part of it is how to keep the previous view and overlay the action sheet

Comment: You should have mentioned this in your inital question... Check the answer from rv7284